# Why only & and | are called bit wise operators?

Tags: c, operators, bit-manipulation

In programming languages operators like & and | are called bit wise operators. My question is even addition(+) and subtraction(-) or to that matter any mathematical expressions are bit wise operations. I mean the calculation happens on binary data as machine cannot understand decimals. I think for addition also there will be an add gate so why only operators like & and |(or) are called bit wise operators.

Comment: You missed `^` which also is a bitwise operator.

Comment: And also the `~` operator.

Comment: Arithmetic operations such as `+` or `-` do not work on individual bits, the higher bits depend on the carry from lower ones, so it's not called "bitwise"

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc If you have a variable `int x = 0;` then execute `x = x-1;` then how exactly would you claim that `-` worked on individual bits? Assuming two's compl. then `-` turned 0x00000000 into 0xFFFFFFFF. Doesn't look very individual to me.

Comment: what i have missed is not so important. my intention is to ask why not others. Anyway thanks for the answer. It helped me understand why the name bit wise.

Comment: @Lundin: did you misread my comment? I said that arithmetic operators **don't work on invidual bits**, not bitwise operators

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Aah, yes indeed, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the bitwise operators only operate on the bits, they do nothing "more" and there's no question of the underlying format.

Addition treats a bunch of bits as a number, which might be signed (or even floating point); this means it must interpret the bits in a particular way (e.g. two's complement, signed magnitude, floating point, and so on), while the bitwise operators treat the bits as just "raw" bits, with no interpretation and no dependencies between bits as there might be in the higher-level numerical formats.

Also, you forgot some: there's also the `^` bitwise XOR operator, `~` which is bitwise not, and of course the shifting operators `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: Might also want to count the shifts (`<<` and `>>`).

Comment: +1 `while the bitwise operators treat the bits as just "raw" bits` - well stated.

Comment: @nil Omg, thanks! Edited, of course. Need more coffee, faster.

Comment: Except... the >> << does not treat the bits as raw bits, in case of signed variables. But I made the same statement in my own answer, even though it is bit of an over-simplification.

Comment: @Lundin `the >> << does not treat the bits as raw bits, in case of signed variables` - Can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: @Acme In case you right-shift a variable of negative value, the result is implementation-defined. The compiler could decide to shift in zeroes (logical shift) or it could shift in the msb (arithmetic shift). In case you left-shift a variable of negative value: undefined behavior, anything can happen, including program crashes.

Comment: @Lundin - i did not understand the latter part as to how left shifting a positive number will not lead to UB (I as this because the statement tends to implicitly mean that). For e.g. `0101010101` (first bit is sign bit) - left shifting one position will make it negative and another positive - so how is it UB in both cases (or only one)?

Comment: @Acme It is only UB in case the value can't be represented. See 6.5.7 of the standard: `The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros." /--/ "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."`

Comment: Thank you so much. I know that there are other operators as well for bit wise operations. My intention is to ask why not others. Any way your explanation helped me to understand why not. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In the C language, there are a lot of operators called bitwise: `& | ^ << >> ~ &= |= ^= <<= >>= ~=`. They have in common that they are only used for bit manipulation on the "raw binary level", regardless of what kind of data the variable contains.

But of course, all operators have the purpose of altering bits. Bitwise is just a naming convention by the C language. Strictly speaking, C groups operators together in different groups with related operators, like this (C11 6.5):

- *Additive operators*  + -
- *Bitwise shift operators* >> <<
- *Bitwise AND operator* &
- *Bitwise exclusive OR operator* ^
- *Bitwise inclusive OR operator* |

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

^ (XOR) and the shift operators are also bitwise operators. The difference between these and other operators is mainly that bitwise operators do not assume a particular encoding of a value, as is the case with the two's complement representation of integers. A small exception to this rule is that >> makes no sense unless the leftmost bit is interpreted as a sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

In bitwise operations, the value of the bit at some particular position in the result **may** depend from the value of the bit in the **same** position in operands but does not depend on bit values in any **other** positions.

With one operand, there are 2 possible inputs (*false, true*)  so 4 bitwise operations are possible (x, not x, 0 and 1). With two operands, there are 4 possible input combinations so in total 16 such operations are possible (*and, or, xor, not x, not y, x, y, 0, 1*, etc).